# Archiving Cucumber Reports from a Jenkins build

Tags: jenkins, cucumber, splunk

i'm running a nightly Cucumber test automation suite through Jenkins, but i'm interested in archiving the reports somewhere and using them for future metrics and auditing activities.

What are my options for archiving Cucumber Reports somewhere?

Should i be looking at tools such as Splunk to consume the reports and build a bespoke Splunk report based on the data? Are there any other tools out there which would better suit this task? Are there any standard tools used for the archiving of Test Automation Reports, which also allows the archived reports to be accessed and displayed.

I'm trying to get an idea of what's the best tool or approach for this task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could post the reports to a data store of your choosing as well as Jenkins. That way you could create a historical store with a scheduled task to compress the reports say weekly or monthly.

This way would remove adding complications into Jenkins itself.

If you are in AWS say, you could look at s3 buckets for example.